# How to map checkboxes for unchecking other boxes in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to be able to select one box or the other by means of checking one will uncheck the other, but I also need it so that I can select neither, which is why I opted for not using radio buttons.

[This is an example of how the checkboxes look now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jDxV.png)

```
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import { useState } from "react";

function myfunc() {

  const [checkedTable, setCheckedTable] = useState(true);
  const [checkedSkip, setCheckedSkip] = useState(false);

  const handleChangeTable = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
    setCheckedTable(!checkedTable);
    if (checkedSkip) {
      setCheckedSkip(!checkedSkip)
    }
  }

  const handleChangeSkip = (e) => {
    setCheckedSkip(!checkedSkip);
    if (checkedTable) {
      setCheckedTable(!checkedTable)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Table style={{width: "100%"}} striped>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>QNAME</th>
        <th>Table</th>
        <th>Fills/Skips</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      {(typeof questions === 'undefined') ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        questions.map((question, i) => (
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>{question}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name={question}
                id={question + " table"}
                checked={checkedTable}
                onChange={handleChangeTable}

              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name={question}
                id={question + " skip"}
                checked={checkedSkip}
                onChange={handleChangeSkip}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))
      )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  )
}

export default myfunc;
```

I have tried mapping the useState and that's why you see e in the onChange functions, but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manage an object for each type of checkbox, something like:

```
const [checkedTable, setCheckedTable] = useState({});
const [checkedSkip, setCheckedSkip] = useState({});
```

When rendering you could call a change handler like `handleChangeCheckbox` which passes the `question` as well as the type of checkbox.

```
questions.map((question, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>{question}</td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={question}
              id={question + " table"}
              checked={checkedTable[question]}
              onChange={() => handleChangeCheckbox(question, "table")}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={question}
              id={question + " skip"}
              checked={checkedSkip[question]}
              onChange={() => handleChangeCheckbox(question, "skip")}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
 ))
```

You could then update the state of each checkbox accordingly:

```
const handleChangeCheckbox = (question, type) => {
    setCheckedTable((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [question]: type === "table"
    }));
    setCheckedSkip((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [question]: type === "skip"
    }));
  };
```

Comment: That is super close to what I'm lookin for. The only issue is that I can't uncheck a box that is checked, it only swaps between the two. I've been having troubles separating it so that I can uncheck it. Any ideas?

Comment: I fixed it, i adjusted the lines to have as follows:

[question]: type === "table" ? !prev[question] : false,
and
[question]: type === "skip" ? !prev[question] : false,

you were a huge help getting there, thank you.

Comment: @MotoMatt5040 - Awesome, you're welcome!